# Registers used by exec() system call arguments

Tags: x86, system-calls, execve

I am trying to know in what registers does exec() system calls arguments are stored.

I first ran a simple C program that does a exec system call and took its object dump and found that RDI was being used for the argument that contains the process to be executed and syscall instruction was being used to call execve in the kernel. I did this in a 64-bit Ubuntu 12.04 OS

Then I ran this program on Ubuntu 11.10 OS(32 bit) running on QEMU. But now in object dump interrupt with no 0x80 was being used and the argument is in EBX.

I am confused on 2 fronts.. why is int80 used in 1 place and syscall in the other and how are the registers for execve system call choosen?

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is that different chip architectures use different *system call conventions* when making a request for service to the running operating system.  Such conventions are part of the *ABI* (application binary interface) defined by an operating system -- other things defined by an ABI include:

- registers (and/or stack layout) used to pass arguments to a function
- which registers a function may use as scratch space, vs. which it must restore to their previous values when returning
- (virtual) memory layout of a program within the processor's address space

Remember that although they are often both supported by the same physical processor (for backwards compatibility reasons) the Intel 64 bit (IA64) and 32 bit (IA32) architectures are still separate, with different (if overlapping) registers available, and with different ABIs.  As you have noticed, these two ABIs differ both in the placement of arguments to a system call, and in the means of signalling to the kernel that a system call is being made.

These days, operating system ABIs are often defined (at least as a suggestion) by the company which offers the particular chip architecture, and so it is usual for all (or most) operating systems running on a given architecture to provide the same ABI, but this was not always the case -- and it is still possible to find differences of the type you note between different operating systems running on the exact same hardware.

Comment: Ok,I got tht. But why is value of EAX (that contains the system call no) 59 for the 64 bit one and 11 for the 32 bit one? Both run similar kernels after all.

Comment: Unfortunately, on Linux the mapping of system call number to system call is different for each architecture -- if I had to guess, I'd guess this was a side effect of the fact that many of the ports of Linux to different processor types started off as independent projects, but I don't know.  As a point of comparison, BSD Unix has traditionally maintained a single system call mapping which was used by all parts.

Comment: You can find the system call mappings for a given Linux architecture by looking in `/usr/include/asm/unistd.h` on a host running that architecture.  As an exception, on Intel hosts, both the IA32 and IA64 headers are installed, in `/usr/include/asm-i386` and `/usr/include/x86_64`, respectively.